# How can I handle the Orange HRMS datepicker in Selenium Java for the PIM Page's date of birth field?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Facing issue while handing the orange HRMS date picker in PIM Page (Date of birth date picker). Here, I share link of the site.

https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/web/index.php/pim/viewPersonalDetails/empNumber/68

username: Admin
Password:admin123

Steps:

1. Login with above username and password
2. Click PIM menu, scroll down and click the edit button in select the DOB field

Tried with different method but not able click it.

Expecting:
To click the specified month, year and date.

```
String date = "10/september/2023";
String[] dateElements = date.split("/");

String dayFromUserInput = dateElements[0];
String monthFromUserInput = dateElements[1];
String yearFromUserInput = dateElements[2];


List <WebElement> monthlist=getDriver().findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='oxd-calendar-selector-month-selected']/following::ul[@class='oxd-calendar-dropdown']"));
int i=0;
int j=0;
for (WebElement ele : monthlist) {
    System.out.println(ele.getText());
    String[] fbmonth = ele.getText().trim().split("\n");
    for(i=0;i<fbmonth.length;i++) {
    
        System.out.println("fbmonth" +i +"="+ fbmonth[i] );
        if (fbmonth[i].equals(monthFromUserInput)) {
            
            WebElement m=getDriver().findElement(By.xpath(fbmonth[i]));
            
            action.scrollByVisibilityOfElement(getDriver(), m);
            action.moveToElement(getDriver(), m);
            action.JSClick(getDriver(), m);
            
            System.out.println(fbmonth[i] + " project is displaying");
```